# URL path shows undefined - issue after redirect on $location in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Here i'm working on a login app using AngularJS. After authentication, when I try to redirect to home page using $location, first the url will change to '/home' but suddenly the path change and shows '/undefined'. Following is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

var currentURL = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+':'+location.port;

app.constant("customConstants", {"value": "false","url": currentURL});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'usrlib/html/login.html',
        controller : 'loginController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'usrlib/html/login.html',
        controller : 'loginController'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'usrlib/html/home.html',
        controller : 'homeController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('loginController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $route, $location, customConstants) {
    console.log("Inside loginController");

    $scope.authenticate = function () {
        var userdetails = {};
             userdetails["username"]=angular.element('#username').val();
             userdetails["password"]=angular.element('#password').val();
            var config_json = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
            $http.post(customConstants.url+"/login",userdetails, config_json)
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, "\t"));
                var resp = response.data;

                if(resp=="success"){
                    alert("Success login")
                    $location.path('/home');

                }
                else{
                    console.log("Login Failed");
                }
             }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response.error);
            });
     };

});

app.controller('homeController', function(customConstants, $scope, $http) {
    alert("Inside homeController");

    $http.get(customConstants.url+"/home")
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("overall_info :: "+JSON.stringify(response.data, "\t"));

     }, function errorCallback(response) {

     });
});
```

In browser it shows:

[image]

Can't find the issue, please help out.

Comment: Are you sure the path in the mapping is correct? Please can you post the structure

Comment: @CrazyMac :  in "routeProvider" i define it like  .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'usrlib/html/home.html',
        controller : 'homeController'
    }) and redirect using  $location.path('/home');  . Do I need to set the path mapping else where?

Comment: Based on what you have posted and if this path is correct, usrlib/html/home.html, then It should load this page. Are you trying to control the application base path anywhere else ? Also what do you see currently now in the browser?

Comment: I think you are controlling the URL using customConstants. I am not sure why do you have to use this. Can you dump and tell what's is being printed for customConstants.url

Comment: If you do not want # in the URL then you need to add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); in the config section or else refer this basic example www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing

Comment: @CrazyMac : it prints like  customConstants.url : http://127.0.0.1:7070

Comment: Is there any reason you use this or you use it to remove the hash. Just for testing, can you change this line as below,
var currentURL = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+':'+location.port + '/#';

Comment: @CrazyMac : I think there is no issue with the customConstants, if i add the '/#', the $http.post method is not working. Actually when i give $location.path('/home');  first the url will change to 'http://127.0.0.1:7070/#/home' but suddenly the path change and shows '/undefined'

Comment: Then may be you are triggering the routing twice and it messes up. What are you trying to do in this line in the homecontroller. $http.get(customConstants.url+"/home")

Comment: @CrazyMac : I'm sending a back-end request. Actually when i define "/" as home page in routeProvider, it works fine and $http.get(customConstants.url+"/home") this request also works fine. But when i set "/" as login page and then redirect to home, it wont work

Comment: I am not following your response. Can you comment out your call to back-end and just test it? I mean the line in the homeController - $http.get(customConstants.url+"/home")

Comment: @CrazyMac : I comment the entire get request but still not working. I even put an alert inside homeController, that too not working. So it is not getting inside "homeController"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142447/discussion-between-crazymac-and-nayana-das).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need.

```
$location.path('/home'); // Wrong
```

Try

```
$location.path('home'); // ryt
```

Comment: Is this not solving the issue

Comment: @JinsPeter : No it is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the **$location** Parameter from your function definition. because unless you invoke the function there is a chance of showing undefined,,